# How to get the output of a second consecutive for-loop within a with-block, within which a .csv file is read?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
from csv import reader    
with open('tsble.csv', 'r') as r:
            rows = reader(r)
            for row in rows:
                print(row)
            print("Second print\n")
            for r in rows:
                print(r)
```

The output of the second for loop in the above python-with-block is not coming. How to get outputs from two or more consecutive for-loops within a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reached to the end of your file, so you can just `seek` back:

```
with open('tsble.csv', 'r') as r:
    rows = csv.reader(r)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    r.seek(0)
    print("Second print\n")
    for r in rows:
        print(r)
```

Comment: By "You reached to the end of your file", Do you mean since 'row' contains the last row, the second for-loop is not giving the output.?. If so what about the change made to 'row' to be 'r'

Comment: @Varuna The variable for _row_ is not important for this context. `rows` pulls the data from `r` so it would be wise to change `r` in the second loop as it overwrites the variable that points to file - meaning it wouldn't work for the third time.

Comment: Ye, you right.I used 'row' even for the second for-loop, after the r.seek(0) operation and it the gave the output just as the first

Comment: A third, forth for-loop is giving the output, But each time after the for-loop 'seek(0)' has to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

`rows` is a generator. As such, the first `for` loop consumes it and the second `for` loop never executes. A possible solution would be to force `rows` into a list:

```
 rows = list(csv.reader(r))
```

Do keep in mind that this will make the code consume more memory. This may matter if the file is on the bigger size. In that case, use @zipa's solution.